# Which Haskell library for computer graphics geometry?

Tags: haskell, graphics, libraries

I would like to do some experiments in computer graphics in Haskell. This will include doing some geometry calculations and ultimately writing a ray tracer. Which library should I pick for easy handling of vectors, matrices and relevant operations on them?

There are few on Hackage including nice looking ones like [vect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect) and [AC-Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AC-Vector), but it's easy to miss a good candidate among so many different libraries.

Comment: This is a marginally bad question... Check out the FAQ on [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). You should probably remove the last sentence from your question to prevent this from becoming a discussion.

Comment: @cha0site Done. It's rather fuzzy to me why is this a case though.

Comment: Your requirements are somewhat vague, but it's still an interesting question IMO.

Comment: I like `linear` to deal with vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For vectors and matrices that are used for transformations, [`vect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect) probably is your best bet. It is optimized for fast, lower-precision (as in `Double` precision as opposed to `Ratio` precision) transformations like you described, and its role as the matrix stack in [`lambdacube`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lambdacube-engine) (as an example of an application where performance is key) shows that it is fast enough for most applications.

For data matrices - that are used for images, for example - you'd probably want to use [`repa`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa), especially when doing data-parallel computations such as ray tracing.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting library called [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-spacevector-space) by Conal Eliott which allows you to lazily compute Taylor series of many analytic functions. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313994/derivative-towers-and-how-to-use-the-vector-space-package-haskell). Not sure about performance, though.

Comment: Vector-space is very useful for the type classes it provides which extend the Num hierarchy (it is still very useful without the linear map and derivative tower stuff). You need to provide your own Point, Vector, etc. datatypes.