# How to differentiate integrals with vector-space library (haskell)

Tags: haskell

When using the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.1) package for derivative towers (see [derivative towers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313994/derivative-towers-and-how-to-use-the-vector-space-package-haskell)) I come across the need to differentiate integrals.
From math it is quite clear how to achieve this:

```
f(x) = int g(y) dy from 0 to x
```

with a function

```
g : R -> R
```

for example.

The derivative with respect to x would be:

```
f'(x) = g(x)
```

I tried to get this behaviour by first defining a class "Integration"

```
class Integration a b where
--standard integration function
integrate :: (a -> b) -> a -> a -> b
```

a basic instance is

```
instance  Integration Double Double where
  integrate f a b = fst $ integrateQAGS prec 1000 f a b
```

with `integrateQAGS` from [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.14.0.1)

the problem comes with values b which represent towers of derivatives:

```
instance Integration Double (Double :> (NC.T Double)) where
  integrate = integrateD
```

`NC.T` is from Numeric.Complex (numeric-prelude).
The function `integrateD` is defined as follows (but wrong):

```
integrateD ::(Integration a b, HasTrie (Basis a), HasBasis a, AdditiveGroup b) =>  (a -> a :> b) -> a -> a -> (a :> b)
integrateD f l u = D (integrate (powVal . f) l u) (derivative $ f u)
```

The function does not return what I want, it derives the integrand, but not the integral. The problem is, that I need a linear map which returns `f u`. The `a :> b` is defined as follows:

```
data a :> b = D { powVal :: b, derivative :: a :-* (a :> b) }
```

I don't know how to define `derivative`. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

edit:

I forgot to provide the instance for `Integration Double (NC.T Double)`:

```
instance  Integration Double (NC.T Double) where
  integrate f a b = bc $ (\g -> integrate g a b) <$> [NC.real . f, NC.imag . f]
      where bc (x:y:[]) = x NC.+: y
```

and I can give an example of what I mean:
Let's say I have a function

```
f(x) = exp(2*x)*sin(x)

>let f = \x -> (Prelude.exp ((pureD 2.0) AR.* (idD x))) * (sin (idD x)) :: Double :> Double
```

(AR.*) means multiplication from Algebra.Ring (numeric-prelude)

I can easily integrate this function with the above function `integrateD`:

```
>integrateD f 0 1 :: Double :> Double
D 1.888605715258933 ...
```

When I take a look at the derivative of f:

```
f'(x) = 2*exp(2*x)*sin(x)+exp(2*x)*cos(x)
```

and evaluate this at `0` and `pi/2` I get `1` and some value:

```
> derivAtBasis (f 0.0) ()
D 1.0 ...

> derivAtBasis (f (pi AF./ 2)) ()
D 46.281385265558534 ...
```

Now, when deriving the integral, I get the derivation of the function `f` not its value at the upper bound

```
> derivAtBasis (integrate f 0 (pi AF./ 2)) ()
D 46.281385265558534 ...
```

But I expect:

```
> f (pi AF./ 2)
D 23.140692632779267 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my question.
The key to the solution is the `>-<` function from the vector-space package, it stands for the chain rule.

So, I define a function `integrateD'` like this:

```
integrateD' :: (Integration a b, HasTrie (Basis a), HasBasis a, AdditiveGroup b , b ~ Scalar b, VectorSpace b) => (a -> a :> b) -> a -> a -> (a:>b) -> (a :> b)
integrateD' f l u d_one =  ((\_ -> integrate (powVal . f) l  (u)) >-< (\_ ->  f u)) (d_one)
```

the `d_one` means a derivation variable and its derivative must be 1. With this function I can now create some instances like

```
instance Integration Double (Double :> Double) where
integrate f l u = integrateD' f l u (idD 1)
```

and

```
instance Integration ( Double) (Double :> (NC.T Double)) where
integrate f l u = liftD2 (NC.+:) (integrateD' (\x -> NC.real <$>> f x) l u (idD 1.0 :: Double :> Double)) (integrateD' (\x -> NC.imag <$>> f x) l u (idD 1.0 :: Double :> Double))
```

unfortunately I can't use `integrateD` on complex values out of the box, I have to use `liftD2`. The reason for this seems to be the `idD` function, I don't know if there is a more elegant solution.

When I look at the example in the question, I now get my desired solution:

```
*Main> derivAtBasis (integrateD' f 0 (pi AF./ 2) (idD 1.0 :: Double :> Double )) ()
D 23.140692632779267 ...
```

or by using the instance:

```
*Main> derivAtBasis (integrate f 0 (pi AF./ 2)) ()
D 23.140692632779267 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do AD on a function which involves numeric integration, without the AD system knowing about integration *per-se*, it should "just work".  Here is an example.  (This integration routine is pretty icky, hence the name.)

```
import Numeric.AD
import Data.Complex

intIcky :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b -> b
intIcky n f a b = c/n' * sum [f (a+fromIntegral i*c/(n'-1)) | i<-[0..n-1]]
  where n' = fromIntegral n
        c = b-a

sinIcky t = intIcky 1000 cos 0 t
cosIcky t = diff sinIcky t

test1 = map sinIcky [0,pi/2..2*pi::Float]
 -- [0.0,0.9997853,-4.4734867e-7,-0.9966421,6.282018e-3]
test2 = map sin [0,pi/2..2*pi::Float]
 -- [0.0,1.0,-8.742278e-8,-1.0,-3.019916e-7]
test3 = map cosIcky [0,pi/2..2*pi::Float]
 -- [1.0,-2.8568506e-4,-0.998999,2.857402e-3,0.999997]
test4 = map cos [0,pi/2..2*pi::Float]
 -- [1.0,-4.371139e-8,-1.0,1.1924881e-8,1.0]
test5 = diffs sinIcky (2*pi::Float)
 -- [6.282019e-3,0.99999696,-3.143549e-3,-1.0004976,3.1454563e-3,1.0014982,-3.1479746e-3,...]
test6 = diffs sinIcky (2*pi::Complex Float)
 -- [6.282019e-3 :+ 0.0,0.99999696 :+ 0.0,(-3.143549e-3) :+ 0.0,(-1.0004976) :+ 0.0,...]
```

The only caveats are that the numeric integration routine needs to play well with AD, and also accept complex arguments.  Something even more naive, like

```
intIcky' dx f x0 x1 = dx * sum [f x|x<-[x0,x0+dx..x1]]
```

is piecewise constant in the upper limit of integration, requires the limits of integration to be Enum and hence non-complex, and also often evaluates the integrand outside the given range due to this:

```
Prelude> last [0..9.5]
10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

'hmatrix' is tied very closely to Double. You can't use its functions with other numeric data types like those provided by 'vector-space' or 'ad'.

Comment: Yes that's true. But it works, when I use the `powVal` function on a `Double :> Double` value. But of course, I lose the information about the derivative. I have to provide this information explicitly, and that's where I am stuck :(